# Copy only file details (file name, size, time) from remote machine in unix

Tags: shell, files, remote, recursive

how can we copy only file details (filename, size, time) from a remote machine in Unix?

For example: I have a directory (`/opt/apache/…/webapps/Context`) placed on a remote machine. Now I want to copy only the metadata (size, time, filename) of the files that reside in this directory and its subdirectories to my local machine, something like `root root 1150 Dec 30 12:11 file.txt`.

Comment: How do you want the output? Do you want just a directory listing or must there be a file on your local system per file on the remote system?

Comment: I need all file names with size, time in the directory/subdirectories. To copy actual file is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a detailed listing of the files in directory `opt/apache../webapps/Context` on remote machine `remotemachine`, use:

```
ssh remotemachine  "ls -l /opt/apache../webapps/Context"
```

If you want to search recursively for all files in that directory *and all its subdirectories*, then use:

```
ssh remotemachine  "find /opt/apache../webapps/Context -type f -exec ls -l {} +"
```

#### How it works

- `ssh remotemachine command`

  This executes `command` on `remotemachine` using secure-shell (`ssh`).  `command` can be any command of your choosing.  In the two examples above, I used:
- `ls -l /opt/apache../webapps/Context`

  This displays the directory listing of `/opt/apache../webapps/Context` in the "long" format.  You may use any of `ls`'s options to select the format or sorting that you prefer.  See `man ls`.
- `find /opt/apache../webapps/Context -type f -exec ls -l {} +`

  This uses `find` to search recursively through subdirectories.  The files it finds are again displayed with `ls`.  `-type f` tells `find` to show only regular files and not directories.  `find` has many options which you may use to select just the files that interest you.  See `man find`.

#### More Options

If you want to save the output to a file, use *redirection*.  For example:

```
ssh remotemachine  "ls -l /opt/apache../webapps/Context" >outputfile
```

If you want both to display the output on the screen and also to save to a file, use `tee`:

```
ssh remotemachine  "ls -l /opt/apache../webapps/Context" | tee outputfile
```